# What is usage of "Position<E>" with Iterators in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, iterator, position

I was studying tree structures with the book named ***Data Structures & Algorithms in Java***, but I have a problem with Code Fragments in this book. All of the code blocks have written with `Position<E>` like this example;

```
public interface Tree<E> extends Iterable<E> {
    Position<E> root();
    Position<E> parent(Position<E> p) throws IllegalStateException;
    .
    .
    .
    boolean isInternal(Position<E> p) throws IllegalStateException;
}
```

What must I use instead of `Position<E>`? Is it a placeholder or a structure that Java includes? If it is, can I use my own `TreeNode<E>` class instead of it?

Comment: There is no `Position` in Java SE API (except in Swing) so it must be a class / interface that is introduced in the book. Could you post it?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, here is the position interface;

public interface Position<E> {
    E getElement() throws IllegalStateException;
}